# Unity - Why UI Text doesnt update in runtime and only updates when run time ends( When I hit play button to stop)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a feature in a space shooter game that records score based on the number of scraps(currency) collected but it seems it doesn't display the updated currency I have in the pool.

ScrapDestroyedScript.cs

```
public class ScrapDestroyedScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public PlayerScoreScript PSSRef;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.tag == "L.Collider Det" || collider.tag == "R.Collider Det") 
        {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }

        else if(collider.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy (gameObject);
            PSSRef.ScrapCollect ();
        }
    }

}
```

PlayerScoreScript.cs

```
public class PlayerScoreScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public int playerScraps;
    public Text textVar;

    public ScrapStatsScript ScrapStatsScriptReference;

    void Start () 
    {

    }

    void Update () 
    {
        print (playerScraps);
        textVar.text = "Scraps: " + playerScraps;
    }


    public void ScrapCollect()
    {

        playerScraps += ScrapStatsScriptReference.ScrapValue;
    }
}
```

ScrapStatsScript.cs

```
public class ScrapStatsScript : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public int ScrapValue;
    public float ScrapSpeed;

    void Start () 
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        transform.Translate (-ScrapSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
    }

}
```

Anything to suggest?

Comment: Is your `print (playerScraps);` even changing?

Comment: yeah it does, just doesnt show it in UI text but only after runtime ends and once i play the the scene again

Comment: You want to show screenshot of the UI before and after you run it? I just want to know the possible cause

Comment: Before: https://imgur.com/a/VXD8N
After: https://imgur.com/a/xOYav
After(when Runtime ends): https://imgur.com/a/j0lLF

Comment: Your screenshot proves that `print (playerScraps);` is not changing. This was my first comment. If `print (playerScraps);` is not changing then the text should not because `playerScraps` is 0.

Comment: yea playerScraps is suppose to be 0 at first then once i collect a scrap it should increase by 10

Comment: Then post a new "After" screenshot after you collect a coin to prove this

Comment: As you can see https://imgur.com/a/wTKiK it updates once i press Play. It seems it carries the value from the previous run time to the next

Comment: Your before/after/runtime-ends screenshots all show 0. What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah it always show 0 and thats my problem